# Routes. Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I update apllication from rails 2 to rails 3.
And I rewrite routes with resources. How to write route to this actions:

```
def delete_attachment
    @object = Article.find(params[:id])
    attachment = Attachment.find(params['attachment_id'])
    attachment.attachment = nil
    attachment.destroy
    redirect_to :action => 'edit', :id => @object.id
  end

  def edit_attachment
    @object = Article.find(params[:id])
    attachment = Attachment.find(params['attachment_id'])
    attachment.title = params['attachment_title']
    attachment.description = params['attachment_description']
    attachment.save
    redirect_to :action => 'edit', :id => @object.id
  end

  def add_attachment
    @object = Article.find(params[:id])

    attachment = Attachment.new
    attachment.attachment = params['attachment_file']
    attachment.title = params['attachment_title']
    attachment.description = params['attachment_description']
    attachment.article_id = @object.id
    attachment.save

    params['attachment_title'] = nil
    params['attachment_description'] = nil

    redirect_to :action => 'edit', :id => @object.id
  end
```

This is right solution?

```
resources :articles do
    delete '/articles/delete_attachment', :to => 'articles#delete_attachment'
    put '/articles/edit_attachment', :to => 'articles#edit_attachment'
    post '/articles/add_attachment', :to => 'articles#add_attachment'
  end
```

I have no way to check it on the server, because there are still many incompatibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the routes to:

```
resources :articles do
  member do
    delete 'delete_attachment'
    put 'edit_attachment'
    post 'add_attachment'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, what abou edit_attachment.Which hhtp verb use get or put?

Comment: According to your code, edit_attachment action is updating the attachment, so use PUT here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have multiple member routes, you can also pass :on to a route, eliminating the block:

Like,

```
 resources :photos do
     get 'preview', on: :member
 end
```